# Why does community rejected my edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I recently [suggested edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/94182) to a question and after 9 minutes user [bmdixon](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/30530/bmdixon) approved my edit and 14mins later [Community](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) rejected my edit but my edit was reflected in question. I cannot understand why my edit was rejected but my edited content was actually displayed in the question in the same format? If my edit was rejected the edit made by the OP(within five minutes) or someone who edited with higher reputation should be displayed right?

[image]

A similar question: [Why did community user reject this edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186786/why-did-community-user-reject-this-edit)

Comment: I think the original poster may have hit "Reject and Edit", perhaps by accident or simply because they are not familiar with the suggested edit system. I *think* you get the generic "conflict" rejection reason when that happens, but I'd need to find a source to confirm that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suggested Edit overwritten by OP edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141867/suggested-edit-overwritten-by-op-edit) on [meta.se]. Related [Why was suggested edit rejected by Community?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171411/286110) @eldarerathis, I experimented "Reject and Edit" just now and Community doesn't give that reject message. The link I mentioned has possible explanation for the behavior, because OP here and the author of the question proposed and asked the question at similar time.